# Identity Server : Grant Type for native mobile apps

Tags: oauth, identityserver3, openid-connect, identityserver4

I have implemented an Identity Server4 and it looks great. Now, I have a requirement to connect a native mobile app(xamarin) to it.Most of the blogs and discussions suggest to use either "Authorization Code" or "Hybrid" flow, and the xamarin example in the github uses "Implicit" flow.

I have been through this documentation on Authorization flow and it does not talk anything about username or password.
https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/endpoints/authorize.html

What I need is to allow the user to supply his/her username and password to the authentication server, and the server should ultimately give back the access code.

1. Which will be the most appropriate authentication flow for this.

Comment: Hi,

What did you end up doing? I'm in kind of the same setup. Xamarin setup with webapi and identityserver. I have the need for both username/password and facebook login. I want thefacebook login to be handled like native so I end up with a token for facebook, and from there I want to hand it over to IdentityServer..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two "mindsets" -

a) the login UI is native in the application

b) the login UI is rendered from the OpenID Connect in a browser

Generally b) is recommended - check the spec:

https://tools.ietf.org/wg/oauth/draft-ietf-oauth-native-apps/

I also did a talk about that last year:

https://vimeo.com/171942749

If you absolutely don't want the redirect/server-based approach, then research the "resource owner password grant" - e.g. here:

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/2_resource_owner_passwords.html

But, I would not recommend it.

Comment: Then in this scenario components such as Xamarin.Auth are not recommended? What if I am using authentication with 3'rd parties ? Access to my webapi is done with Google/MSFT, does this mean we have to implement authentication with external providers from the Identity api and then supply a web-page that'll be accessed by a Xamarin/Whatever WebView ? ...

Comment: What should be the mindset for Register? I am trying to achieve it within the native app - which works. But stuck at being able to autologin the user post register. Dont want to ask the user to re-enter their cred on the login page(in the browser). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60187173/oidc-register-auto-login-flow-for-mobile-apps

Comment: @leastprivilege the vimeo link does not work, could send a working one?